# Equations: Why does formula symbol index notation "ff" cause such big letter spacing?

Tags: equations, symbols, indexing

The formula symbol index notation `ff` is causing some ugly letter spacing in comparison to other index notation letters.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        t=\frac{h\varepsilon_{eff}}{w}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    t=\frac{h\varepsilon_{ett}}{w}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, the letter spacing distance between those two `f`'s is very huge in comparison to the `t`'s of the second equation. Therefore the second equation appears well balanced and a bit more nicely than the first one.

Do you all write `eff` the way I'm doing, or is there some special trick to reduce this ugly letter distance?

---

**Update (2019/01/19):** The user `marmot` has posted an approach of writing the index notation in text mode:

```
t=\frac{h\varepsilon_\mathrm{eff}}{w}
```

I am not sure if it is typographically allowed to write index notations in text mode? I thought in equations everything has to be `italic`, no?

Comment: You probably want `t=\frac{h\varepsilon_\mathrm{eff}}{w}`.

Comment: @marmot: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! I am not sure about, but I think it is typographically wrong to write any formula symbol indexes as text? I think they have to be written `italic` as well (like the whole equation), no?

Comment: OK, I thought `eff` would stand for `effective`. If these are indices, you are of course right.

Comment: @marmot: You are completely right, it stands for `effective`. So you think it is permitted to write the index notation as text in such cases?

Comment: @Dave: I can hardly believe that the “eff” in your formula is meant to denote the product of the three quantities “e’ and “f squared”.  Contrary to what you seem to believe, indices that denote words (like “effective”, or “efficacious”) **must** be written, in formulas, in upright (Roman) font.

Comment: Yes, of course. Texts should always be typeset upright, only symbols are italic AFAIK. (I personally would do `t=\frac{h\,\varepsilon_\mathrm{eff}}{w}` but there are users who do not like the `\,`).

Comment: @GuM and @marmot: Thank you very much for your extremely kind help! Good to know that! In the past I seriously thought that even indices for word denotations should be written in common `italic` mode - thank you very much for your enlightenment! You can post this as an answer if you want...

Comment: You can use italic but use `\mathit{eff}` never use the default math italic for multi-letter identifiers it is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product pf variables and not a word.

Comment: No, I repeat, it is common practice to write that particular type of pedices upright, and I think ISO regulations actually mandate so (I cannot swear for this, I’m not particularly fond of ISO regulations, they also dictate that the “d” in `\int f(x)\,dx` should be upright, something I’ll never yield to unless under threat of death).  I also wanted to remark about using `\mathit`, but @DavidCarlisle has already taken care of this!

Comment: If *eff* is an abbreviation for *effective* or some word like this, it is definitely text. Hence `\mathrm{...} is possible, but I would strongly recommend to use AMS's `\text{...}` (defined when you load  `amsmath` package) which produces true text with proper font, spacing and size.
So have a try to `t=\frac{h\varepsilon_\text{eff}}{w}`. And  the same for *ett*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make this italic—but use `\mathit{eff}`.  Never use the default math italic for multi-letter identifiers.  That is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product of variables, not a word.  Alternatively, you can use `\mathrm{eff}` if you want upright. Both of those fonts are designed for words.

Comment: Thank you very much! So this is valid for multi-letter identifiers, but for single-letter identifiers I am still allowed to keep up the math mode?

Comment: @Dave yes sure you _should_ use the math italic font for single letters. All variables should be called x all functions should be called f and math fonts are optimised for single letter identifiers, it's the way it is:-)

Comment: @Dave: If the subscript denotes a *variable*, it should be in math italic (_e.g._, `m_{i}` for the i-th mass), but if the subscript is an abbreviation for a *word*, best practice (and, I repeat, probably also ISO directive) is to set it upright (_e.g._, `m_{\mathrm{E}}` for the mass of the Earth).

Comment: @GuM when I did math for a living, I never referred to anything that related to a real word (or the real world:-)

Comment: @GuM there are no ISO standards for typesetting mathematics in general, unfortunately ISO 80000 is sometimes interpreted that way, but that's just notational conventions for one particular subject area of engineering and has no relevance to mathematical typesetting in general

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I knew that (I said that I write `\int f(x)\,dx`); but, as I understand it, the question did arise in the context of engineering (electrical engineering, I guess).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use negative thin space `\!`. With this you can reduce the space between the letters without invoking the `mathit` or `mathrm`. You can adjust the spaces as needed.

[image]

To typeset your example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
      t=\frac{h \, \varepsilon_{e\!f\!\!f}}{w}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
t=\frac{h\varepsilon_{ett}}{w}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```